# Loading some html content in WebView does not load images in ARC app

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I have a WebView in Android app which is able to load html content with images (img tag) properly. But if I load the same content in ARC app WebView, it does not load images.

Edit:

**Note:** This problem is happening only on desktop versions of Chrome. It works fine on Chromebook.

Comment: Where is this content coming from (Internet, assets, local files, other)? How are you loading it (`loadUrl()`, `loadData()`, `loadDataWithBaseURL()`, other)? Do you have any sample HTML and Java that reproduces this problem that you can share? I had no problems with ARC loading https://commonsware.com using `loadUrl()`, for example.

Comment: I am using loadDataWithBaseURL() method. The html content is coming from internet.

Comment: I can send you the html content which does not load images. How do I share it with you?

Comment: FYI, this issue is happening only on desktop versions of Chrome. I ran it on Chromebook and it worked fine. Edited the question.

Comment: "How do I share it with you?" -- add it to your question. If it's something that you do not want to share publicly, then you probably should not be sharing it privately either. Ideally, you cut that HTML back to something that reproduces the error with minimum cruft and minimum concerns about publication. Your "works on Chrome OS/not on Chrome" behavior definitely adds to the mystery.

Comment: I think it will happen to any html content with images on desktop versions of Chrome.

Comment: When you say desktop version of Chrome do you mean you run the app in ARC Welder? Can you share the code that loads the page and possibly the URL it's loading?

Comment: Yes I tried running the ARC app generated from ARC Welder in Linux and Mac. When you load an html page in WebView, the image in it does not load. Works fine in Chromebook though.

Comment: My WebViews load without issues including images therefore again: Can you share the code that loads the page and possibly the URL it's loading?

Comment: Did you try it in desktop chrome?